# Azure Luis Migration issue

Tags: azure, bots, azure-language-understanding

I went on Luis. It told me to migrate the Luis. I migrated it and now most of my luis got reset to default. Losing all my old work. How can I restore it? Thanks

Comment: can you provide more details about the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not migrated LUIS v2 to v3 before June 19 2020, all existing constraint features will be automatically migrated to the required feature flag. No programmatic changes are required to your prediction API and no resulting change on the quality of the prediction accuracy.

The following elements need to be migrated with changes:
Entities
Hierarchical entity
Composite entity
Roles - roles can only be applied to a machine-learning (parent) entity. Roles can't be applied to subentities
Batch tests and patterns that use the hierarchical and composite entities

If above content has been changed, this is because the difference between versions. If you have other content changed during the migration, please share what items changed so that we can take a look

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring-entities